# Formatting number as current in word using vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I m using vba codes to generate reports from excel to word and I am getting stuck. The number I am copying seems to not have the format from excel,  I need it to be formatted into currency i.e. $1,000 or $5,212,345 and right now it just showing as 1000 and 5212345.

Here is my codes, I have a method or data member not found error.

```
.TypeText "Total Written Premium: " & ws4.Range("I" & LR12)
.Format (ws4.Range("I" & LR12) = "$#,##0.00_)")
```

Comment: I tried ws4.Range("I" & LR12).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);($#,##0.00)" but its no use.  You are correct that its under with but it has multiple lines of codes prior to it that has been working fine so that is why I am only posting the line that I am getting stuck with.

Comment: Is the error occurring on the `.TypeText` or the `.Format` instruction?

Comment: As for the implicit `With` block, you might want to read [mcve].

Comment: (a) What is the value of the variable `LR12`?  (b) What is the `With` block object that this code is referring to?  (c) I don't think the `Format` property of any object I have come across takes a `True`/`False` parameter, so I doubt if setting the Format property to `(ws4.Range("I" & LR12) = "$#,##0.00_)")` will be meaningful.  (d) Please post a MCVE as suggested by @Mat'sMug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.TypeText "Total Written Premium: " & ws4.Range("I" & LR12)
```

You're fetching the `Range`'s `Value`, implicitly. This would be more explicit:

```
.TypeText "Total Written Premium: " & ws4.Range("I" & LR12).Value
```

A cell's *value* doesn't have any formatting. It's not a *representation* of the underlying value, it's *the value itself*.

If the cell is already formatted as currency then you need to get its `Text` instead:

```
.TypeText "Total Written Premium: " & ws4.Range("I" & LR12).Text
```

Comment: in excel everything is formatted but when I m using the vba codes to transport the number, the formatting is lost.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this answer says. Because you're reading the cell's `Value` (implicitly). Read the cell's `Text` instead.